# esri-leaflet NOT showing in angular typescript it doesn't recognize VECTOR

Tags: angular, typescript, esri-leaflet, esri-leaflet-geocoder

I am not able to show the map or to use the search  offered by esri-leafleft: here the code of the ***typsescript*** file.

```
import {  Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css";
import "esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder";
import * as esri from "esri-leaflet-geocoder";

/*import * as esri from "esri-leaflet";*/ this one is not working i already installed it.




 @Component({
selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
```

})

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  marker;
title = 'Events Management';
constructor() { }





ngOnInit(){

const apiKey = "I already have the key";

const basemapEnum = "ArcGIS:Navigation";

const map = L.map("map", {
  minZoom: 2

}).setView([-33.8688,151.2093], 14); // Sydney

L.esri.Vector.vectorBasemapLayer(basemapEnum, {
  apiKey: apiKey
}).addTo(map);



const searchControl = esri.Geocoding.geosearch({
  position: "topright",
  placeholder: "Enter an address or place e.g. 1 York St",
  useMapBounds: false,
  providers: [esri.Geocoding.arcgisOnlineProvider({
    apikey: apiKey,
    nearby: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2093
    },
  })]
}).addTo(map);

const results = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

searchControl.on("results", (data) => {
  results.clearLayers();
  for (let i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const lngLatString = `${Math.round(data.results[i].latlng.lng * 100000)/100000}, ${Math.round(data.results[i].latlng.lat * 100000)/100000}`;
    const marker = L.marker(data.results[i].latlng);
    marker.bindPopup(`<b>${lngLatString}</b><p>${data.results[i].properties.LongLabel}</p>`)
    results.addLayer(marker);
    marker.openPopup();
  }
});
  }
}
```

**ERROR TypeError: leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.esri is undefined**
this is the error i get  i get in the console i've looked everywhere but found nothing, even if i changed L with only esri it would not work with the Vector part

Answer (score 0):

I don't know angular, but you have commented out where you import esri-leaflet:

```
/*import * as esri from "esri-leaflet";*/
```

You should rename your import from esri-geocoder so that it doesn't interfere with your esri import:

```
import * as esri from "esri-leaflet"
import * as EsriGeocoder from "esri-leaflet-geocoder"
```

Without that esri import, the esri object is not imported and attached to `L`, and any call to anything `L.esri` will not work.